# Dynamically Add RadzenTextBox based on value of RadzenNumeric

Tags: c#, blazor, radzen

I am creating an app in Blazor/C#, using mostly Radzen components.  My goal is to have a user select the number of items to add, using RadzenNumeric, and then dynamically create that number of text boxes.

I found a working example, that almost fits my needs,  with . but, I can't seem to get it to fire from the RadzenNumeric Change="@onchange_n".

Here is what I had so far:

```
<RadzenNumeric Value="@N" class="w-100" Change="@onchange_n" />  Sum: @total
```

I feel that it's the Value attribute that I am getting wrong.  I based it on the working example I found below.  This one works:

```
<input type="number" value="@N" @oninput="onchange_n"> Sum: @total
```

Code:

```
@foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0,N))
{
var ii=i;
<input type="number" value="@MyList[ii]"
@oninput="(e) => resum(ii, e)"><br>
}


@code
{
private int N = 0, total = 0;
private List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
private Void onchange_n(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
N=0;
if (Int32.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out int n)) N = n
MyList.Clear();
MyList.AddRage(Enumerable.Range(0,N).Select(_=>0));
StateHasChanged();
}

private void resum(int i, ChangeEventArgs e)
{
var n = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out int auxn)) n = auxn;
MyList[i] = n;
total = MyList.Sum(x=>x);
}
}
```

I don't understand why it will fire onchange_n properly from the (<input type="number") box, but not the RadzenNumeric. is Value not the proper place for @N ?
what am I missing.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `input` element's `@oninput` parameter is `EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs>` but the type of `RadzenNumeric` component's `Change` parameter is `EventCallback<TValue>`.

Try:

```
<RadzenNumeric TValue="int" Value="@N" class="w-100" Change="@onchange_n" />  Sum: @total

@code {
    private int N = 0, total = 0;
    private List<int> MyList = new List<int>();

    private void onchange_n(int value)
    {
        N = value;
        MyList.Clear();
        MyList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(_ => 0));
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void resum(int i, ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var n = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out int auxn)) n = auxn;
        MyList[i] = n;
        total = MyList.Sum(x => x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.  It helped me understand what was going wrong.  Your solution worked.  Thank you.